# Raw SQL in DFC (Documentum)

Tags: java, documentum, dfc

In DFC one can execute SQL directly (bypassing DQL) using the `IDfSession.apiExec()` method. The problem is that the method is marked as *deprecated* in the current (6.x, 7.x) versions of the DFC API.

Here's some example code using the deprecated method:

```
IDfSession session;
(...)
String sql = "UPDATE dm_sysobject_s SET r_modifier = 'hacker' WHERE r_object_id = '<some_id>'";
session.apiExec("execsql", sql);
```

This works fine, but as already mentioned `apiExec` is deprecated.

I've also tried an alternative approach:

```
(...)
IDfQuery query = new DfQuery(sql);
query.execute(session, IDfQuery.DF_EXEC_QUERY);
```

To my knowledge this ought to work, but I keep getting the following message:

```
[DM_QUERY_E_REG_TABLE_PERMIT_IN]error:  "You have insufficient privilege to UPDATE the dbo.dm_sysobject_s table."
```

I get the same error message when using `IDfQuery.DF_QUERY`, but anyway DF_EXEC_QUERY is the one that should be working -- or? I am of course trying this out with a super user account, so I wouldn't know which privileges I'm missing.

*Is there a good, non-deprecated way to execute raw SQL statements from within DFC?*

I would also like to add that I *am* very aware that raw SQL is strongly discouraged because it bypasses Documentum's security model. I am also aware that I can use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` in my Java code, but that doesn't make the method any less deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this myself and decompiled `DfSession`. In the `apiExec()` method DFC uses some internal calls that are available to "outsiders", and this enables the possibility of creating your own "apiExec() equivalent".

Here's a simple example from within a BOF class (a TBO implementation, for instance):

```
import static com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty;
...
import com.documentum.dmcl.impl.DmclApi;
...

public class MyBofClass extends MyBofInterface {
    ...

    private boolean execSql(String sql) throws DfException {
        return execApi("execsql", sql);
    }

    private boolean execApi(String command, String args) throws DfException {
        return execApi(getSession(), command, args);
    }

    private boolean execApi(IDfSession session, String command, String args) throws DfException {
        StringBuilder apiBuilder = new StringBuilder(command);
        apiBuilder.append(',');
        apiBuilder.append(session.getSessionId());
        if (!isNullOrEmpty(args)) {
            apiBuilder.append(',');
            apiBuilder.append(args);
        }
        return DmclApi.getInstance().exec(apiBuilder.toString());
    }
    ...
}
```

(One should probably restructure this into static util classes or whatever is preferred.)

The crucial part here is of course the `DmclApi.getInstance().exec()` call. This is an ugly hack, but no worse than the original `apiExec()` in my opinion. It's a reimplementation, really.

Answer (score 1):

You can support direct connection to your sql server as to Documentum Content Server. And execute your sql statements in those connection.
The other thing is to find a way substitute your SQL stuff with smth else. Create sql views, stored procedures and so on.

Comment: But what if the DFC client doesn't have access to the DB service directly? This is often the case (only privileged clients -- like the Content Server -- may connect to a DB, or the DB is on another network segment, etc.). It's also an "even more discouraged" way to do it as no-one but the CS should really access the DB. But thanks for your reply, it is certainly a creative approach that I didn't think about that might work well in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `getCommand`, `setQuery` and `execute` chain, like this:

```
IDfApplyExecSQL execSQL = DfAdminCommand
        .getCommand(IDfAdminCommand.APPLY_EXEC_SQL);
execSQL.setQuery("UPDATE....");
execSQL.execute(session);
```

If you still get the permissions message, it may be a problem with your SQL server or your connection to it.